# Screenshotting mobile site in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using this script to take a screenshot of what I want to be the mobile site at the dimensions of an iphone:

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(args[1], function () {

    page.viewportSize = { width: 414, height: 736 };

    page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 414, height: 736 };
    page.render(args[2]);
    console.log(args[2]);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

On some sites this seems to work but on other sites it incorrectly shows what it actually looks like.

For instance, here is what it generates for Google:

[image]

Google obviously have a mobile site so where am I going wrong?

Comment: it has probably to to with the UserAgentString that is sent. http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the UserAgent

here information on how to set it: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html

This Code Works for me:

```js
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30';

page.open("http://www.google.com", function () {

    page.viewportSize = { width: 414, height: 736 };

    page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 414, height: 736 };
    page.render("./test.jpg");

    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried the iphone6 useragent and it is now the right size but the background is black.  I tried adding `document.body.bgColor = 'white';` inside `page.open` but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Guerrilla this happens when, phantomjs tries to render transparent color and save it as an **jpg**, try using `page.render("./test.jpg",{format:"png"});`. Is a reported issue https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12724

Comment: I just rendered as png and it works.  Filesize isn't high so it's all good.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When I debug, the Google.com page has `min-width` specified. So, even if you resize the page inside Phantom, Google.com page will continue to render with `min-width`.

It will be same for even other sites that have `min-width` specified.

[image]